# Error gets thrown when calling require_once on widget.php

Tags: widgets

I have the following code in my functions.php:

```
require_once('widgets.php');

function Menu_Widget() { 
    register_widget( 'Menu_Widget' );
  }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', 'Menu_Widget' );
```

The content of widgets.php doesn't really matter, since the error appears even if widgets.php is empty.

With these lines, going to the wp-admin page gives me the following errors:

```
/var/www/html/page-name/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4139

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in /var/www/html/page-name/wp-admin/widgets.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/page-name/wp-content/themes/dpsglohmar2017/functions.php(105): require_once() #1 /var/www/html/page-name/wp-settings.php(424): include('/var/www/html/d...') #2 /var/www/html/page-name/wp-config.php(88): require_once('/var/www/html/d...') #3 /var/www/html/page-name/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/var/www/html/d...') #4 /var/www/html/page-name/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/var/www/html/d...') #5 /var/www/html/page-name/wp-admin/about.php(10): require_once('/var/www/html/d...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/page-name/wp-admin/widgets.php on line 51
```

Both of these errors appear when the lines above are the only ones in functions.php. The errors don't appear on my local machine, only when executed on the server. These errors also appear when all plugins are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renamed widget.php to widget-custom.php. Seems to work now.